# Error in .subset(col, i) : object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggally

I am trying to assign colors to text in a ggpairs plot matrix depending on column correlations (high correlations are red, low ones are blue):

```
colors <- colorRampPalette(c("blue", "red"))(100)
correlation_color <- function(data, mapping, ...) {
  cor = print(cor(data[,toString(mapping$x)], data[,toString(mapping$y)]))
  col = colors[round(abs(cor) * 100)]
  print(col)
  print(class(col))
  ggally_text(paste("Cor: ", round(cor, 2), sep = ""), aes(color = col))
}

plt = ggpairs(sales_df,
        lower = list(continuous = wrap("smooth", color='blue', size=0.5, method='loess')), diag = list(continuous = wrap("barDiag", binwidth=1, color='blue')),
        upper = list(continuous = wrap(correlation_color))
        ) + theme_light()
plt
```

First of all, I don't understand why I need to cast `mapping$x` to string before subsetting the data frame using it.

Besides that, my code fails with the following error:

```
Error in .subset(col, i) : object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable
```

This does not occur when I replace aes(color = col) by aes(color = "red"). I also tried:

```
ggally_text(paste("Cor: ", round(cor, 2), sep = ""), color = col)
```

But this produces no color on the text (besides the warning `The plyr::rename operation has created duplicates for the following name(s): (`colour`)`)

What is happening? The errors/warnings make absolutely no sense to me. What is the type `symbol`? Why can't I replace a string with another string? Is there a simpler way to achieve my goal?

**EDIT**

Here's a minimal nonsensical example dataset:

```
sales_df <- data.frame(X1=seq(1,9,length.out = 15), X2=1:15)
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data so that we can run this ourselves?

Comment: You are correct to take `color` outside of `aes`.  You need to give a blank `mapping` with `gally_text`, as well: `ggally_text(paste("Cor: ", round(cor, 2), sep = ""), mapping = aes(), color = col)`

Comment: Indeed, you are right. Thank you. If you're willing to post an answer I'll gratefully accept it. Out of curiosity, how was I supposed to figure this out from the docs or any online sources? It seems very random to me.